# Mysqli Database Connection - failing to authenticate users and Admin

Tags: php, database, mysqli

We move our website to a new server and now it fails to authenticate users and admin.

The old serve is still live and if I change the IP to the old serve I can login as admin without problems but it's slow.

```
    **Database connection**

    function doDB_MySQLi() 
    {
    global $link;

    $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','Username','Password','Database_name','3306') or die(mysql_errors());

    if (!$link) 
    {
        printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }

}


function doMySQLi() 
{
global $link;
$link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','Username','Password','Database_name','3306');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

The server is Windows Server 2008 Web Edition.

**ERROR: You do not have access to this area.**

Comment: You should at least post your error message.

Comment: Error message: You do not have access to this area.

Comment: Have you created the old users on the new server with the same details

Comment: check if you given permission to the user from new computer?

Comment: @Anigel yes imported a database dump.

Comment: @Mlungisi database dump don't contain authentication in MySQL

Comment: Was it a dump of the entire database server including all the mysql database etc and did you flush privileges after importing it?

Comment: @Anigel it was separate database table because of our internet speed. After importing; I created a new user and assigned rights.

Comment: and as per my previous question did you FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after creating the users?

Comment: Nope i didnt, help with command.